# Running an instance of a java based web application

Tags: java, web-services, web-applications

I'm trying to build a QA site for my school which students can use to ask and answer course-related questions.

I searched a bit and stumbled upon this interesting project called [mamute](https://github.com/caelum/mamute).

There is no detailed description on how to get it up and running and I have no experience setting up an environment to run such an application. All of the links they provide in the readme and on their website are dead. Bummer.

1. What kind of application is this?
2. What environment do I need to get it up and running?

Comment: If you take the time to read the readme file, you will see that it is a Java web application which runs on a MySQL database.  You should try to follow their setup guide.  If you get stuck at a specific point, then ask on Stack Overflow.  For now, I am voting to close as too broad.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just use something like one of the free forum/online community services?

Comment: If you are stuck this early and this is not for a learning experience but because you need the tool for others to use, I would suggest not going down this path.

Comment: @Thomas Do you have any specific suggestions?

Comment: Not really, but a quick search resulted in pages like this: https://www.a2hosting.com/blog/5-outstanding-forum-platforms-set-online-community/

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen If you take the time to read the title of this question you would know that I saw it was a java web application. The point of the first part of the question is to reassure this fact, the second (and main part) is asking about how to set it up as there is no setup guide as far as I know (their links do not work).

Answer (score 1):

What i get by your question is like you want to create just a dynamic website where student can question and answer various topics. If i am not wrong ! you can do following.

Step 1: Create a DB in MySql and connect it with your WebApp using JDBC.

Step 2: Create the necessary tables in DB and apply proper constraints and     checks.

Step 3: Try to develop and design a dynamic Web site either on JSP or Servlet.

*You can also use framework(Angular) or client side script(JS,Jquery) to make your app more user friendly.*

Creating Such a question answer site is not a really tough task. All you need a proper knowledge of technology and your expected product too.

Just some smart Web coding in JSP and  queries in DB you can easily get the desired functionality.

Comment Below to move this answer in a right direction.

[You can also refer this link for a thematic design for your app](https://athemes.com/collections/best-question-answer-wordpress-themes/)

Comment: If OP are stuck this early, it may not be as easy as you think to do development work.

Comment: You are right Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen. But person asked about the environment besides technical infrastructure of the project so this is all about the idea we can discuss. Besides this your valuable suggestions are always welcome here.

Comment: @NightCoder Your high level overview (the steps) is helpful thanks. From what I understood is I need to set up a DB and connect it to my WebApp (mamute). You are describing a more general approach on how to develop the WebApp myself which is also fine, I would prefer to adopt mamute and add functionality I need to it. Do you have any recommendations on websites where I can learn more about how to set-up, develop and maintain such WebApps?

Comment: @Anna I would recommend trying a step and then if you get stuck ask a more focused question.  I'd be more than happy to jump in the water with you, but what you asked above is just too broad.